# Are WAMS tables decoratable?

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

With local embedded SQLite table classes, one can decorate columns with attributes such as PrimaryKey, AutoInc, MaxLength(NN), and Indexed. It would seem that the more big metal-ish WAMS (nee SQL-Azure) tables, being, as they are, basically MS SQL Server tables, would provide that capability, too.

But the only thing that I see that's possible from the WAMS portal is to "Set Index" on the selected column.

Is it possible *now* to decorate columns with additional attributes (something I'm unaware of), or is this a feature planned for the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better late than never.  I'm not sure if it's a coming feature or not, however, with the database in SQL Azure (or SQL Database), you can certainly manipulate the underlying table.  I'd be cautious in doing so to make sure you don't make breaking changes, but you could certainly add indexes and constraints to a column.

Also, something I've done is make use of stored procedures and functions, and then calling them from the WAMS script.